# jQuery highlight selection and change when another is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to take the following code and make it so if I click on one link it toggles a class to add a background but when I click another link it should remove said class and add it to the new link.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});


<a href="#">Link1</a>
<a href="#">Link2</a>
<a href="#">Link3</a>
```

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5LepN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5LepN/3/)

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: So simple.  I guess I should have thought of that :\